# SQL Query to return most recent row per user

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table structure

So I have these columns in my table:

```
UserId   Location   Lastactivity
```

Let's say that there are 4 results with a UserId of 1 and each location is different. Let's say

`index.php, chat.php, test.php, test1.php`

.Then there are also timestamps.

Let's also add one more with a UserId of 4 location of `chat.php` and time of whatever.

Time is in the `timestamp` format.

I want to get it so that my sql query shows one result from each userid but only the latest one. So in 2 it would show the row which was added to the table most recently. Also I don't want it to show any results that have a lastactivity that was 15 or more minutes ago.

For the example I would just be displaying two rows returned.

Does anyone know what I should do?

I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM session WHERE location='chat.php' GROUP BY userid
```

That returns two results but I believe if there are multiple results for the userid it returns a random one, it also returns results that have a lastactivity of more than 15 minutes.

I am using mysql

------MORE INFO-------

I want to query the database for all the rows where location='chat.php'. I only want one row per userid which is determined by whichever is the most recent submission. Then I also don't want any that are older than 15 minutes. Finally I want to count the number of rows returned and put them into a variable called testVar

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post a sql fiddle

Comment: What do you mean? How?

Comment: First thing is to get a SQL manual. To limit the time range you will use a `WHERE` clause. Then you can choose the latest timestamp for any given user using `GROUP BY` and `MIN`. Finally, knowing userid and timestamp, you can get the rest with a `JOIN` of the table against itself.

Comment: Can you do me an exmaple? I'm not good with using that sorta stuff :(

Comment: Show your expected result set with some sample data set more better if you provide sample data [*@sql fiddle*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: HAVING MAX(sysdate-lastactivity) < 15*60 .. would help? not sure of oracle's sysdate equivalent of mysql.

Comment: A SQL fiddle is a set of data where you (and others) can play and see the results. For example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e4d4/1/0 - you'll have to fix some errors.

Comment: I am very confused... My table name is session. After the query is returned I want to get the amount of rows returned into a variable called: testVar. I then want to minus one from testVar to give me my final result. Can someone help me by giving me the full code? Please submit as an answer so I can mark as correct if it is :) @iserni @

Comment: Let's just provide proper DDLs and a desired result set shall we? Let's.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you are looking for boils down to you wanting the username and location with the most recent time stamp. So, you want to ignore all the records whose last activity is not the greatest.

```
Select sum(1) as testVar
From session s
Where location='chat.php'
and datediff(minute, s.lastactivity, getdate()) < 15
and  not exists (Select *
                            From session s2
                            Where s.userid = s2.userid
                            and   s2.lastactivity > s.lastactivity);
```

For each record, this query checks to see if there is another record for the same user where the time stamp is more recent. If there is, we want to ignore that record. We only want the rows where a record with more recent activity doesn't exist. It is a little strange to think about it this way, but the logic is equivalent.

By default this query will only grab one row per user, so a group by is not necessary. (This does get a little hairy if the time stamps are exactly the same for two records. In this case, no records will be pulled back)

Comment: Unfortunately my previous comment still stands.  
I am very confused... My table name is session. After the query is returned I want to get the amount of rows returned into a variable called: testVar. I then want to minus one from testVar to give me my final result. Can someone help me by giving me the full code? Please submit as an answer so I can mark as correct if it is :)

Comment: @user3474238 I don't quite understand what testVar is. You want the number of rows (minus one) for the user?

Comment: No, I want to query the database for all the rows where location='chat.php'. I only want one row per userid which is determined by whichever is the most recent submission. Then I also don't want any that are older than 15 minutes. Finally I want to count the number of rows returned and put them into a variable called testVar

Comment: @user3474238 you should add this information into your question, it isn't clear right now.

Comment: Added it. Are you able to help me?

Comment: So in reality, you are looking for the number of unique users that were in chat.php in the past 15 minutes, is that correct?

Comment: @user3474238 Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55535/discussion-between-jenn-and-user3474238).